# OpenGL: screen-to-world transformation and good use of glm::unProject

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, mouse-picking

I have what I believed to be a basic need: from "2D position of the mouse on the screen", I need to get "the closest 3D point in the 3D world". Looks like ray-tracing common problematic (even if it's not mine).

I googled / read a lot: looks like the topic is messy and lots of things gets unfortunately quickly intricated. My initial problem / need involves lots of 3D points what I do *not* know (meshes or point cloud from the internet), so, it's impossible to understand what result you should expect! Thus, I decided to create simple shapes (triangle, quadrangle, cube) with points that I *know* (each coord of each point is 0.f or 0.5f in local frame), and, try to see if I can "recover" 3D point positions from the mouse cursor when I move it on the screen.

Note: all coord of all points of all shapes are known values like 0.f or 0.5f. For example, with [the triangle](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle):

```
float vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
};
```

## What I do

I have a 3D OpenGL renderer where I added a GUI to have controls on the rendered scene

- Transformations: `tx`, `ty`, `tz`, `rx`, `ry`, `rz` are controls that enables to change the `model` matrix. In code

  ```
  // create transformations: model represents local to world transformation
  model = glm::mat4(1.0f); // initialize matrix to identity matrix first
  model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(tx, ty, tz));
  model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rx), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
  model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(ry), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
  model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rz), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
  ourShader.setMat4("model", model);
  ```

  `model` changes only the position of the shape in the world and has no connection with the position of the camera (that's what I understand from [tutorials](https://learnopengl.com)).
- Camera: from [here](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera), I ended-up with a camera class that holds `view` and `proj` matrices. In code

  ```
  // get view and projection from camera
  view = cam.getViewMatrix();
  ourShader.setMat4("view", view);
  proj = cam.getProjMatrix((float)SCR_WIDTH, (float)SCR_HEIGHT, near, 100.f);
  ourShader.setMat4("proj", proj);
  ```

  The camera is a fly-like camera that can be moved when moving the mouse or using keyboard arrows and that does *not* act on `model`, but *only* on `view` and `proj` (that's what I understand from [tutorials](https://learnopengl.com)).

  The shader then uses `model`, `view` and `proj` this way:

  ```
  uniform mat4 model;
  uniform mat4 view;
  uniform mat4 proj;
  void main()
  {
     // note that we read the multiplication from right to left
     gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
  ```
- Screen to world: as using `glm::unProject` didn't always returned results I expected, I added a control to not use it ([back-projecting by-hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692988/opengl-math-projecting-screen-space-to-world-space-coords)). In code, first I get the cursor mouse position `frame3DPos` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796287/screen-coordinates-to-world-coordinates)

  ```
  // glfw: whenever the mouse moves, this callback is called
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  void mouseCursorCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xposIn, double yposIn)
  {
      // screen to world transformation

      xposScreen = xposIn;
      yposScreen = yposIn;

      int windowWidth = 0, windowHeight = 0; // size in screen coordinates.
      glfwGetWindowSize(window, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);
      int frameWidth = 0, frameHeight = 0; // size in pixel.
      glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &frameWidth, &frameHeight);
      glm::vec2 frameWinRatio = glm::vec2(frameWidth, frameHeight) /
                                glm::vec2(windowWidth, windowHeight);
      glm::vec2 screen2DPos = glm::vec2(xposScreen, yposScreen);
      glm::vec2 frame2DPos = screen2DPos * frameWinRatio; // window / frame sizes may be different.
      frame2DPos = frame2DPos + glm::vec2(0.5f, 0.5f); // shift to GL's center convention.
      glm::vec3 frame3DPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
      frame3DPos.x = frame2DPos.x;
      frame3DPos.y = frameHeight - 1.0f - frame2DPos.y; // GL's window origin is at the bottom left
      frame3DPos.z = 0.f;
      glReadPixels((GLint) frame3DPos.x, (GLint) frame3DPos.y, // CAUTION: cast to GLint.
                   1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
                   GL_FLOAT, &zbufScreen); // CAUTION: GL_DOUBLE is NOT supported.
      frame3DPos.z = zbufScreen; // z-buffer.
  ```

  And then I can call `glm::unProject` or not ([back-projecting by-hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692988/opengl-math-projecting-screen-space-to-world-space-coords)) according to controls in GUI

  ```
  glm::vec3 world3DPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  if (screen2WorldUsingGLM) {
      glm::vec4 viewport(0.0f, 0.0f, (float) frameWidth, (float) frameHeight);
      world3DPos = glm::unProject(frame3DPos, view * model, proj, viewport);
  } else {
      glm::mat4 trans = proj * view * model;
      glm::vec4 frame4DPos(frame3DPos, 1.f);
      frame4DPos = glm::inverse(trans) * frame4DPos;
      world3DPos.x = frame4DPos.x / frame4DPos.w;
      world3DPos.y = frame4DPos.y / frame4DPos.w;
      world3DPos.z = frame4DPos.z / frame4DPos.w;
  }
  ```

  **Question**: `glm::unProject` doc says `Map the specified window coordinates (win.x, win.y, win.z) into object coordinates`, but, I am not sure to understand what are object coordinates. Does object coordinates refers to local, world, view or clip space described [here](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems)?
- Z-buffering is *always* allowed whatever the shape is 2D (triangle, quadrangle) or 3D (cube). In code

  ```
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enable z-buffer.
  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // also clear the z-buffer
  ```

In picture I get

[image]

The camera is positioned at (0., 0., 0.) and looks "ahead" (`front = -z` as z-axis is positive from screen to me). The shape is positioned (using `tx`, `ty`, `tz`, `rx`, `ry`, `rz`) "in front of the camera" with `tz = -5` (5 units following the `front` vector of the camera)

## What I get

### Triangle in initial setting

[image]

I have correct `xpos` and `ypos` in world frame but incorrect `zpos = 0.` (z-buffering is allowed). I expected `zpos = -5` (as `tz = -5`).

**Question**: why `zpos` is incorrect?

If I do not use `glm::unProject`, I get outer space results

[image]

**Question**: why "back-projecting" by-hand doesn't return consistent results compared to `glm::unProject`? Is this logical? Arethey different operations? (I believed they should be equivalent but they are obviously not)

### Triangle moved with translation

[image]

After translation of about `tx = 0.5` I still get same coordinates (local frame) where I expected to have previous coord translated along x-axis. Not using `glm::unProject` returns oute-space results here too...

**Question**: why translation (applied by `model` - not `view` nor `proj`) is ignored?

### Cube in initial setting

[image]

I get correct `xpos`, `ypos` and `zpos`?!... So why is this not working the same way with the "2D" triangle (which is "3D" one to me, so, they should behave the same)?

### Cube moved with translation

[image]

Translated along `ty` this time seems to have no effect (still get same coordinates - local frame).

**Question**: like with triangle, why translation is ignored?

## What I'd like to get

The main question is why the `model` transformation is ignored? If this is to be expected, I'd like to understand why.
If there's a way to recover the "true" position of the shape in the world (including `model` transformation) from the position of the mouse cursor, I'd like to understand how.

Comment: [tag:glm] != [tag:glm-math]

Comment: The translation in a perspective scene depends on the depth of the object (distance of the object to the "camera")

Comment: @Rabbid76: new to OpenGL, not sure to get what you mean. Can you elaborate. I have updated the "What I'd like to get" section

Answer (score 0):

> Question: glm::unProject doc says Map the specified window coordinates (win.x, win.y, win.z) into object coordinates, but, I am not sure to understand what are object coordinates. Does object coordinates refers to local, world, view or clip space described here?

As I am new to OpenGL, I didn't get that object coordinates from `glm::unProject` doc is another way to refer to local space. Solution: pass `view*model` to `glm::unProject` and apply `model` again, or,  pass `view` to `glm::unProject` as explained here: [Screen Coordinates to World Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796287/screen-coordinates-to-world-coordinates).

This fixes all weird behaviors I observed.